# Por que meu return não retorna o i do for?

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


int BuscaLinear(int *sequencia[], int tamanho, int valor)
{

    int i;
    for(i=0;i<tamanho;i++)
    {
        if(sequencia[i] == valor)
        {
            return i;
        }
    }
    return -1;
}

int main()
{
    int tamanho, valor, resultado, j;
    int sequencia[10] = {11,22,33,44,55,6,7,8,9,1};

    tamanho = 10;

    printf("Digite o valor a ser encontrado: \n");
        scanf("%d",&valor);

    resultado = BuscaLinear(sequencia, tamanho, valor);

    if(resultado != -1)
    {
        printf("O valor esta na posicao %d do vetor!",resultado);
    }
    else
    {
        printf("O valor não foi encontrado");
    }


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: O laço for não conta i++ e sempre retorna -1
Minha IDE é o code blocks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

O seu metodo `int BuscaLinear(int *sequencia[], int tamanho, int valor)` está recebendo um ponteiro de vetores. Declare assim:

```
int BuscaLinear(int *sequencia, int tamanho, int valor)
//ou
int BuscaLinear(int sequencia[], int tamanho, int valor)
```

Assim quando for verificar o valor de dentro do seu vetor, vai recolher o valor inteiro e não o endereço da posição do vetor.

Comment: Realmente você está certo.
Muito Obrigado mesmo.

Comment: @Felipe se funcionou, você pode clicar no V verdinho do lado da pontuação do Brumazzi, pra aceitar a resposta e marcar como resolvido.

Comment: @Bacco eu nunca usei uma ide online, vi que ela conseguil encontrar o valor, coisa que nao costuma funcionar no pc, vc saberia o prq?

Comment: @BrumazziD.B. eu testei do seu jeito e funcionou também, eu acho que o compilador usado no IDEONE deve ter algum tipo de otimização pra essas coisas. Não deveria funcionar dos dois jeitos, na verdade, só do seu. O IDEONE é melhor pra testar coisa rápida mesmo. Realmente, nesses casos é melhor usar um compilador "de verdade" pra testar C

Comment: Creio que a explicação desse comportamento que funcionou no IDEONE se deva ao fato de, no compilador deles, ponteiros e `int`s tenham o mesmo tamanho. Nos casos de divergência (como no code::blocks), ou o ponteiro tinha 64 bits ou o `int` era de 16 bits